# How do I search in the postgresql using Typeorm and return the mutated value for relation?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a User entity with a Role relationship in an application **Nestjs**.

```
@Entity()
class User {
  ...
  @ManyToOne(() => Role, {
    eager: true,
  })
  role?: Role;
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Role extends EntityHelper {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name?: string;
}
```

when I want get users from the DB I do:

```
this.usersRepository.find({ 
      relations: {
        role: true,
      },
    })
```

and I get data like this:

```
{ id: 1,  name: "John", role:  { id: 2, name: "user" }}
```

but I don't want to get the role as an object, I just want the name from this
Example:

```
{ id: 1,  name: "John", role: "user" }
```

So, my question is **how can I get the relation and return only the value of `{ ... role: "user" }`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using *[QueryBuilder](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder)*:

```js
this.usersRepository.createQueryBuilder('User')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('User.role', 'Role')
  .select(['Role.name as role', 'User.id as id'])
  .getRawMany()
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But now I have one more question. When I get values with `. getRawMany()` I have only what I selected with `.select`.
Example: `[..., { id: 1, name: "user" }]`

Is there any way to return all values from entity User, but make changes while I select the Role relation?

Comment: @RichVoronov Since we are using *alias* and *getRawMany* to change the result's format, there isn't any way to tell the *typeORM* to keep other columns unchanged. So you need to keep adding columns in *select* scope.